# What can I do to the links people add so that it doesn't harm my website in terms of SEO?

Tags: seo, sitelinks, technical-seo

I have a website about profiling. People can create a profile here and put a link to the website.

It's hard to keep track of whether the links people add are of good quality or of poor quality. For this reason, what can I do to these links in a way that will not harm me in terms of SEO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If users are adding links to your website, you can report them to google bots with the `rel` feature.

`rel="sponsored"` : Mark links that are ads or paid placements (commonly called paid links) as sponsored.

`rel="ugc"` : Mark links to user-generated content (UGC) such as comments and forum posts as ugc.

`rel="nofollow"` : Mark as nofollow when other values are not valid and you don't want Google to associate your site with or crawl your site from linked pages.

So in this case you can give `rel="nofollow"` to the links in the profile.

[Google article for this topic](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/qualify-outbound-links)